# Extra characters being added when writing a CSV

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I am currently using python, to read one CSV file and then just write the last column to a different CSV file.

My code for reading and writing is:

```
with open('source.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    with open('result.csv', 'wb') as result:
        wtr = csv.writer(result, delimiter=',', quotechar='|' )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow((r[2]))
```

The input looks like this:

```
#SYMBOL_NAME,TIMESTAMP,VALUE
,20140909230500.000000,0.000000
,20140909231000.000000,0.000000
,20140909231500.000000,0.000000
,20140909232000.000000,0.000000
,20140909232500.000000,0.000000
```

I am not interested in the timestamp and because of the software generating it, in this instance symbol name is an empty column.

I would expect my output to be like this:

```
VALUE
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

However I am actually getting this:

```
V,A,L,U,E
0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Now I'm pretty sure that's because of `delimiter=','` in the `csv.writer` part. However when I try to set  `delimiter=''` to remove the commas I am told it must be at least one character string.

When I remove the `delimiter` parameter all together then I get exactly the same output.

Comment: Your original code was very close. It seems you tried to create a tuple, based on the additional parentheses in your code. If you'd just done this, it would have worked: `wtr.writerow((r[2],))` (although the list solution below is better). See [Returning tuple with a single item from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682093) for more info.

Comment: The additional parentheses were from another question I found when googling how to write only column in a csv. I probably should've looked into the differences between my case and the one in that question, because he was trying to remove a column (therefore listing the ones he wanted to keep in double parenthesis) whereas I want to keep one and remove the rest. I think nico had the same idea as you and his soultion worked. But thanks for the link, it was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

writerow() expects a list as argument. 
When you give a single string like this ...

```
wtr.writerow((r[2]))
```

... it will interpret the strings characters as list items and put them as individual columns into the csv.
Do this instead

```
wtr.writerow([r[2]])
```